# smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $L \cap P(L_\alpha)$ is uncountable

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, constructibility

Let $V$ denote the von Neumann universe and $L$ Gödel's constructible universe.  For any set $X$, let $P(X)$ denote the power set of $X$.

Assume that $0^\sharp$ exists (and ZFC).

What is the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $L \cap P(L_{\alpha})$ is uncountable?  (If $V = L$, then $\alpha = \omega$, but if $0^\sharp$ exists, then $\alpha > \omega$.)

Comment: It’s $\omega_1$.

Comment: I suspected so.  Do you have a reference for a theorem that implies this?

Comment: If $0^\sharp$ exists, then every cardinal is inaccessible in L.

Comment: Ah, so $L \cap V_\alpha$ is countable for all countable $\alpha$, too, since $L \cap V_\alpha$ is the $V_\alpha$ of $L$.  Thank you.

Comment: In ZFC alone, the $\alpha$ in the title can be described as: (1) If genuine $\omega_1$ is a successor cardinal of $L$, then $\alpha$ is its immediate predecessor cardinal of $L$. (2) If genuine $\omega_1$ is a limit (and therefore inaccessible) cardinal of $L$, then it is equal to $\alpha$.  The additional hypothesis that $0^\#$ exists implies that case (2) occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Really, this was answered in the comments; I'm putting this answer down to move this off the unanswered queue. I've made this CW and will delete it if one of the original commenters adds their own answer.*

---

We have in $L$, for each (infinite) $\alpha$, the following bijections:

- $f_\alpha:\alpha\rightarrow L_\alpha$.
- $g_\alpha: \mathcal{P}(L_\alpha)^L=\mathcal{P}(L_\alpha)\cap L\rightarrow L_{(\vert\alpha\vert^+)^L}$.

Hence $\vert\mathcal{P}(L_\alpha)^L\vert=\vert(\vert\alpha\vert^+)^L\vert$. Now assuming $0^\sharp$ we have that $\omega_1^V$ is a limit cardinal in $L$, so for each $\alpha<\omega_1^V$ we have $\vert\mathcal{P}(L_\alpha)^L\vert=\aleph_0$.

So the answer to your question is $\omega_1^V$.

---

Note that all this requires is that $\omega_1^V$ be a limit cardinal in $L$. More generally, let $\kappa$ be the supremum of the $L$-cardinals whose $L$-successor is $<\omega_1^V$; then the $\kappa$th level of $L$ is the first whose $L$-powerset is truly uncountable.

Comment: OK, except I think you meant $P(L_\alpha)^L = L \cap P(L_\alpha)$, not $P(L_\alpha)^L = P(\alpha) \cap L$.

Comment: @JesseElliott Whoops, quite right - fixed!